# How to display excel file in streamlit?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, streamlit

I'm trying to display the complete excel data in streamlit but why does it look different from the original?

[image: the right side is the original excel file and on the left side is the excel file that is in streamlit]

```
from streamlit_option_menu import option_menu
import pandas as pd

# 1. as sidebar menu
with st.sidebar:
    selected = option_menu("Product", ["BFR CORPORATE", 'BFR mikro', 'BFR Consumer', 'BRF'], 
        icons=['play', 'play'], menu_icon="cast", default_index=1)
    selected
    print(selected)
df = pd.read_excel("contoh.xlsx")
st.dataframe(df)
```

Comment: the right side is the original excel file and on the left side is the excel file that is in streamlit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **Streamlit AgGrid Component** which is installed as `pip install streamlit-aggrid` to display your dataframe. That might handle the problem you are facing.

With regards to the colour, I am pretty sure will have to write some **CSS** to acomplish that.

Import the module as `from st_aggrid import AgGrid`, after installing it.

```
from st_aggrid import AgGrid

AgGrid(df)
```

You might want to go through the ***[AgGrid Doc](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/global-style-customisation-colours/)*** for more information because it comes with a bunch of features which you might be interested, with regards to the styling of dataframes.

I will recommend you to visit ***[streamlit-aggrid component](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/components)*** to have a glance on how the module is implemented in streamlit.